# Using LINQ, how to select conditionally some items but when no conditions select all?

Tags: c#, linq, select, subset

I want to select elements from myCollection using myFilters for filtering:

```cs
var myFilters = new List<string> {"111", "222"};
var myCollection = new List<SomeClass> {
                      new SomeClass ("111"), 
                      new SomeClass ("999")
                   };

from filter in myFilters
from item in myCollection
where item.Name == filter
select item
```

would return the "111" item.

However, if myFilters is empty I want to return all the items from myCollection.

```cs
var myFilters = new List<string> ();
var myCollection = new List<SomeClass> {
                          new SomeClass ("111"), 
                          new SomeClass ("999")
                    };

// Here's where I'm lost...
from filter in myFilters
from item in myCollection
where item.Name == filter
select item
```

would return all items ("111" and "999").

Comment: You won't be able to do this with a single query because the types are different. In one case you're returning an IEnumerable<SomeClass> and in another you're returning an IEnumerable<string>. Things would be different if your query ended with select item.Name instead of select item.

Comment: "first collection" and "second collection" would be clearer if the local variable names were referenced instead. Something like: "However, when `myFilters` is empty, I want to return all the items in `myCollection` without filtering."

Comment: You're right. Much clearer now I think.

Comment: I know I am little late, can you provide code of your SomeClass? I wonder what it's constructor returns.

Comment: Well, a constructor returns an instance of SomeClass.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If these collections are going to be sizable, then I recommend using a join. It would look something like this:

```
var result = 
    myFilters.Any() ?
        from item in myCollection
        join filter in myFilters
        on item.Name equals filter into gj
        where gj.Any()
        select item
    : myCollection;
```

Opportunities for using joins are easily overlooked. This join approach will outperform the contains approach when the lists are remotely large. If they're small and performance is acceptable, then use whichever seems the clearest.

Answer (score 5):

```
var result = myCollection
                   .Where(i => (!myFilters.Any() || myFilters.Contains(i.Name)));
```

Answer (score 2):

The best you're going to be able to do is project the filters into SomeClass. Something like:

```
var results = myCollection.Any() ?
    myCollection.Where(item => myFilters.Contains(item.Name)) :
    myFilters.Select(f => new SomeClass (f));
```

Comment: Note that this is *not* a subset of filtered instances from `myCollection` but a projection of new `SomeClass` instances created from the matching `myFilters` values.

Comment: It doesn't work (in LINQPad 4) when myFilters is empty. The OP wrote "if the second collection is empty" but meant the filters collection. If you have no filters you should get the entire collection; instead (with this query) you get an empty collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = myCollection.Where(s => !myFilters.Any() ||
                                     myFilters.Contains(s.Name));
//EDIT: commented these lines..based on comment by @Servy
//var result = myCollection.Where(s => myFilters.Count == 0 ||
//                                     myFilters.Contains(s.Name));
```

Maybe it would be better to count filter collection only once:

```
bool isFilterEmpty = !myFilters.Any(); 
//bool isFilterEmpty = myFilters.Count == 0;    //...or like this
var result = myCollection.Where(s => isFilterEmpty || 
                                     myFilters.Contains(s.Name));
```

**EDIT**

I'd even say that the answer by @itsme86 is correct, but, I guess, he has confused your collections. So his answer should look somehow like this:

```
var results = myFilters.Any()
                 ? myCollection.Where(item => myFilters.Contains(item.Name))
                 : myCollection;
```

Comment: Rather than `Count() == 0` you can use `Any()`.  It will not only perform better (it only needs to get the first item to know if there are any vs. needing to fetch every item to get the count) but it also semantically means exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Servy Actually I've got `Any` variant in my answer. Anyway, thanks for clarification.

Comment: Lifting the `Any()` out of the where predicate is a good move performance-wise. A nice thing about leaving the `Any()` in the predicate is if the query is held onto and either the `myFilters`  or `myCollection` lists are altered (e.g., cleared, items added, items removed), then subsequent iteration will provide the updated result.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var myFilters = new List<string> ();
var myCollection = new List<SomeClass> {new SomeClass ("111"), new SomeClass ("999")};

// Here's where I'm lost...
from filter in myFilters
from item in myCollection
where item.Name == filter || !myFilters.Any()
select item
```

Selecting from two collections performs a join based on your where clause. The join condition above says join on item.Name equal to filter OR select it if there are no filters available.